# NSURLSession & NSURLSessionConfig - Discarding Config Headers

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, nsurlsessionconfiguration

I am having an issue with `NSURLSession` & `NSURLSessionConfiguration` and I am not sure if it is my code or I have an incorrect understanding of how the framework behaves.

The issue I am facing is that headers I set at the session level are not present in the `NSURLSessionTask` created from the session.

Here is a small example:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration* config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{ @"TestHeader" : @"TextHeaderValue" };

NSURLSession* session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];
NSURLSessionDownloadTask* task = [session downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];

NSLog(@"%@",task.originalRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields.description);
NSLog(@"%@",task.currentRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields.description);
NSLog(@"%@",session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders);
```

The code above outputs:

```
(null)
(null)
{TestHeader = TextHeaderValue}
```

From my understanding of the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSessionConfiguration/HTTPAdditionalHeaders), any task or request created from the session should inherent the HTTPHeaders from the session. Is my understanding correct? If so, can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header is being sent according to Charles Proxy:
"TestHeader TextHeaderValue".

This seems to be a display problem with the way headers are set in `NSURLSessionConfiguration` and `NSURLSession`. Perhaps one should not assume that the `allHTTPHeaderFields` property is set when using `NSURLSession`.

Comment: Good call. I checked the header in the proxy and it was there as well.